# Proving a function continuous at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Define for $-\pi<\arg z<\pi$ $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{z}}$$ and define $$f(0)=1$$
**Question** Prove that $f(z)$ is continuous at $0$.

My try- Define $$g(z)=\sqrt{z}$$
Define $g(0)=0$.
Let, $\epsilon>0$ be given.
Then there exists $\delta=\epsilon^2>0$ such that $$|g(z)-g(0)|=\sqrt{|z|}< \sqrt{\epsilon^2}=\epsilon   $$ when $|z|<\delta$.
Hence, $g$ is continuous at $0$.
So we get $f(z)$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: Prove that f(z) is continuous at $0$

Comment: @vitamin d Please answer. Any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f(z)=\frac1{1-\sqrt z}$ is continuous at $z=0$, we need to show that for any given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|z|<\delta$, we have $|f(z)-1|<\varepsilon$.

Proceeding, we first impose the restriction $|z|<r<1$ and cut the plane such that $\arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
|f(z)-1|&=\left|\frac{\sqrt z}{1-\sqrt{z}}\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{|z|^{1/2}}{|1-|z|^{1/2}|}\\\\
&\le \frac{|z|^{1/2}}{1-\sqrt r}\\\\
&<\varepsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|z|<\delta=\min\left((1-\sqrt r)^2 \varepsilon^2, r\right)$

Comment: @Marl Viola Excellent and prompt answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Maths You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: +1 for the answer. I will give it a check mark shortly.

Comment: Should we define $f(0)=1$ or it is evident from the definition of $f(z)$ that $f(0)=1$?

Comment: Yes, $f(0)=1$ is clear from $f(z)=\frac1{1-\sqrt z}$ since $\sqrt 0=0$ regardless of how we cut the plane.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am giving your answer a check mark.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Thank you!